# PHP Error for Forms

Tags: php, html, css

I want to keep my div layout to my site when being directed with my error codes. Thing is I don't want multiple errors to have two separate css/div layouts. Here's what I got so far:

```
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
  $error_message .= '<font color="blue">The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br /></font>';
}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
  $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
  $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
  $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
```

I want them all to open up on a page and have the same layout. If there are more than one errors, I want them to not each have separate code. How do I do that?

Comment: The code that you provided will not put each message in a separate div, just on a separate line.

Comment: Question is a bit vague

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: Okay let's try this again. I don't want my contact form going to a page that has "The comments you entered do not appear to be valid." I want my errors to go to back to the original form. With "invalid response" beside what was wrong. Here's the form: http://www.airman-usa.com/site_project/contact.html

Comment: sorry, but iframes and especially in "this century" is pretty tacky and takes up more room for nothing. (no disrespect there Dave) ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The OP didn't tag JavaScript, so yeah....

Comment: @DaveChen I think the OP's new at this and probably doesn't really know *what* they wanted. Your answer works and don't know why you deleted it. I just feel that iframe for doing what the OP wanted to achieve was a bit much. I suggested Ajax but OP never responded, so I ended up deleting my comment about it. They either ignored it, didn't see it or didn't know what I meant by that. It sure wasn't the *cleaning agent*, that's for sure ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I AM new to PHP. Semi okay with java, but not really that great. I'd rather do everything in css/html personally because that's what I'm better at. Thank you all for your input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you're asking for a single div to show any errors, something like this:

```
<div id="errors">
    <?php echo (!empty($error_message) ? $error_message : ""); ?>
</div>
```

But if you want the errors to show up on the same page as the form, you're far better off doing that in Javascript. Put something like this on your page:

```
<form>
    Sample: <input id="sample" type="text" onKeyUp="validateInputs()">
    <button type="button">Button Text</button>
</form>
<div id="error-div"></div>

<script>
    function validateInputs() {
    var errorMessage = '';
    var sampleText = document.getElementById('sample').value;
    if( !sampleText || sampleText.length < 4 ) {
        errorMessage = 'input "Sample" must be as least 4 chars in length';
    }
    if( errorMessage.length > 0 ) {
        document.getElementById('error-div').innerHTML = errorMessage;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('error-div').innerHTML = 'no errors';   
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/terrymorse/ojqnxdqb/).

Comment: @talentless_hack But if you want input validation on the same page as the form, then you're much better off doing that in JavaScript.

Comment: Would I place this in the contact.html?

Comment: thanks I'll look into that. It's an ongoing project so no worries.

Comment: @talentless_hack Yes, you would put the script in the page containing the form, I'll mock up a sample.

Comment: *"Would I place this in the contact.html?"* - @talentless_hack Unless you instructed your system to treat `.html` files as PHP, it won't work. You'd need to use a `.php` extension.

Comment: JS is the way to go with this, especially in this day and age ;-)

Comment: @terrymorse You do have a point.

Comment: @Fred-ii and terrymorse do you two have any links I can refer to help me further with this?

Comment: @talentless_hack Here's a simple tutorial on [form validation with JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp). If you have further questions, please ask.